# I am trying to downgrade from SSD 50GB To Standard 30 GB but Google cloud wont allow me

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machines, google-compute-engine

I am trying to down grade from SSD PD 50 GB to standard PD  using the snapshot method, but when I select the snapshot source Google won't allow me to choose standard PD below 50. I want 30GB standard PD because it's free and I don't have much use of the instance except some small applications.

I tried every method available on the Internet but nothing is working. Finally support pointed me here that I might get some help.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud does not support resizing persistent disks smaller.

Comment: so what do you suggest in this case do i need to make a new instance or is their a work around this like clone my instance or something ?

Comment: @Shinobi - I recommend doing nothing. The money you save is not worth the time. Otherwise, you must use a third-party program or create a new instance and manually copy your data. Then you will have the cost of running two instances at the same time which will defeat your future savings.